# How to override inline HTML image via css image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a form template I am working on, which has a default inline image.

```
<input src="//assets.emailmeform.com/images/submit-orange.png?RU1GLTAyLTI3" type="image" alt="Submit" onmouseover="return true;">
```

Is there any way of overriding this? I have

```
#ID input[alt="Submit"]{
    background-image: url("url here")no-repeat !important;
```

However the result was the CSS image that I assigned was under the default inline image. Is there a way to hide the inline image so that the CSS image will appear on top?

Comment: <input src="url" type="image" alt="Submit" onmouseover="return true;"> Here is the default inline code for the button.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/av24k8f6/).

What I basically did there is that I had set the width and height of the image (picture of a sparrow) to 0 so that it would not show up anymore. And instead I had added a background image to replace it (picture of a parrot).

**HTML**

```
<input src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/House_Sparrow_mar08.jpg/1024px-House_Sparrow_mar08.jpg" alt="submit" type="image">
```

**CSS**

```
input{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  padding: 1000px 1000px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Ara_ararauna_Luc_Viatour.jpg/1024px-Ara_ararauna_Luc_Viatour.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Cheers,